# No match in regex if character at beginning or end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying in regular expression to not match if '-' is at the end of a string.
Here's a partial of my regex (this is looking at domain part of url, which can't have symbols at beginning or end, but can have '-' in middle of string:

```
(([A-Z0-9])([A-Z0-9-]){0,61}([A-Z0-9]?)[\.]){1,8}
```

This also has to match 1-character domains - that's why I have ? on the end character & 0,61 on the center part.

So, in short is there a regex code to prevent matching for '-' if it's at the end of the string?  And if you can prevent it for beginning, then that would be great too.

Matched input:  site. 
Invalid input: -site. or site-.

Comment: There are so many edge cases with URLs that a regex really isn't the best way to do it. For example you can use a negated character class to get rid of hyphens but you'll need to include any character that's bad in a URL. Look behinds are slow and I think it suffers from the same problem.  A quick google turned up this: https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/,  there are probably others.

Comment: also your `{0,61}` and the second check is unnecessary ... just use `{1,61}`. (though that doesn't account for sub-domains and i think it should be `{1, 63}`

Comment: @Cfreak has a point: regexes are not really cut out for URLs. I tried various suggestions from [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/3377150) and they were all far too lenient. [This page](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149) also suggests a regex for URLs, but it is similarly lenient. I'd go with the URI.js suggestion, OP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in short is there a regex code to prevent matching for '-' if it's at the end of the string? And if you can prevent it for beginning, then that would be great too.

Yes you can use negative lookaheads for this:

```
/^(?!-|.*(\.[.-]|-\.|-$))(?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,62}\.){1,8}[A-Z0-9]{3}$/gim
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oN2jB0/10)

Comment: I'm trying to implement the '-' at end but not having much luck:  tried this (([A-Z0-9])([A-Z0-9-](?!.*\-$)){0,62}[\.]){1,8}  Also tried wrapping new code in brackets - how do you use it in my example?

Comment: Ok, I added some examples.

Comment: Well it doesn't work - still need help in getting the code written properly.

Comment: Ok, could you explain what the first parenthesis is all about, so I understand what it's doing.

Comment: `(?!-|.*(\.-|-\.|-$))` is negative lookahead. It is denying presence of hyphen at start, end and before/after a period

Comment: Is there a way to have only 1 dot for each subdomain?  I tried putting it in brackets, but it's still allowing double dots.

Comment: Wonderful, it's working great now - thanks for the help - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
^(([A-Z0-9^-])([A-Z0-9-]){0,61}([A-Z0-9]?)[\.^-]){1,8}$
```

I'm not 100% sure it will work with JS regexes.  The idea is: `^` matches beginning of string, `$` matches end, and `^-` in a character class means "anything not a hyphen".